# Vscode one line comments in HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I would like to make comment with "CTRL+ /" like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtcDx.png)

But when i pressed CTRL + /, comment is change like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkeC0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Place your cursor where you'd like to add the comment. Then, CTRL + /

Comment: I would like to make block comment as single line comment